# Agile 40-hour week

Tags: project-management, agile

Have you ever worked on a (full-time) project where using Agile methodologies actually allowed you to accomplish a 40-hour work-week? If so, what were the most valuable agile practices?

Comment: What do you mean by 40-hour week? Are you asking wether anyone managed to NOT do any overtime using Agile methods?

Comment: Agile development is no "heal-all" for a death-march. Like any method, it can be misused and abused by the team, especially team leads and management.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not about programming withoin site rules.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, I'm on a 40 hour (actually it's 37.5 hours or so, that's what my contract says) on a project that was run with SCRUM from the beginning. That was about 2 years ago and the first time we implemented SCRUM. It's the project with the least amount of overtime for me personally, and it's also a PC game we're developing. I'm not even in "crunch" mode right now even though we're shipping an open beta on Friday.

We have learned a lot since then about SCRUM and agile. The single most valuable lesson from my point of view is: pod sizes must be reasonable ... we started out with pods with 12-20 members, that didn't work out well at all. A maximum of 10 should not be exceeded. It's too easy to agree on "flaky" and "vague" tasks because otherwise the standup & task planning meetings would take too long. So keep the pod size small and the tasks specific and get the product owner or sign-off's together with those who will work on the task.

Also, with a bi-weekly task planning schedule you have to get every Product Owner to agree on the task list and priorities for the current sprint, and new task requests should be issued before that planning meeting or else it will be ignored for the current sprint. This forced us to improve on inter-pod communication.

Answer (score 2):

Scrum and management that is willing to buy into it.

Fair sprint planning.  When you negotiate your own sprint you can choose what  your team can accomplish rather than have tasks being handed down from above. Having your sprint commitment locked in (management can't change it mid-sprint) gives freedom from the every changing whims of people.

A well maintained, prioritized backlog that is maintained **cooperatively** by the product owner and upper management is very useful.  It forces them to sit down and think about the features they want, when they want them and the costs involved.  They will often say they need a feature *now*, but when they realized they have to give up something else to get what they want their expectations become more realistic.

Time boxing. if you are running into major problems start removing features from the sprint rather than working extra hours.

You need managerial support for you process without it agile is just a word.

Did I mentioned enlightened management?

Answer (score 2):

Not being able to complete the tasks in a 40 hour week could be due to several things.

I see that this could happen in the early sprints of a Scrum project because the team wasn't sure of:

1. the amount of work they can do in the sprint and might bite off more than they can chew, and
2. their ability to estimate accurately the amount of points to award to blocks of work, or
3. the amount of effort required to perform "a point's worth" of work.

They may also be overly optimistic in what they can accomplish in the time alloted.

After that we get into several of the bad smells of Scrum, specifically:

1. a team isn't allowed to own its own workload, and maybe
2. management overrides decisions on what should be in a sprint

If any of these cut in then you are:

1. doing Scrum in name only, and
2. "up the creek without a paddle."

There's nothing much you can do apart from correct any problems in the first list, but this will only come with experience.

Correcting the two points in the second list will require a major rethink of how the company is strangling, not employing, Scrum best practises.

HTH

regards,

Rob

Answer (score 2):

It may sound tough, but let's be realistic. Use of agile or any other flavour of a software process has nothing to do with a 40 hour week. Normally the amount of weekly work hours is stipulated within the employment contract and developer can use their discretion to put any additional unpaid work.

Please let’s not attribute magic healing powers to whatever your preferred software process. It can provide a different approach to risk management, different planning horizon or better stakeholder involvement; however, unless slavery is still lawful there you live the working day starts when you come through the door and ends when you go home.

It is as much up to a developer to make sure that the contract of employment is not breached as to their management. Your stake is limited by the amount of pay you get and the amount of honest work hours you agreed to give in return, regardless of a methodology used.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly.

For the me the most important things that helped (in order of importance):

1. Cross-functional team - having programmers, testers, technical writers and sales/services people in the same team and talking to each other daily (daily call) was great.
2. Regular builds and continuous integration
3. Frequent reviews/demos to stakeholders and customers. This reduces the risk and time lost to it only for the period of iteration (Sprint).
4. Daily Call or Stand up meeting

Answer (score 1):

Adding to all of the above (inaccurate estimates, badly implemented Scrum, etc.), the problem could to be the lack of understanding of your team's [Velocity](http://www.scrumalliance.org/articles/39-glossary-of-scrum-terms#1110), something as simple as "how much work a team can accomplish", but which is not that [easy to find as it may seem](http://jan-so.blogspot.com/2007/11/velocity-not-so-simple-value.html).

Answer (score 1):

As both a Scrum Master and personnel manager, I have been a strong advocate of the 40-hour work week.  I actively discourage team members from working over 40 hours as productivity drops quickly as the work-life balance shifts.  I have found recuperating from an late-night work day often takes longer than the extra hours worked.

When it is well-run, Scrum aids in minimizing the "cram" that often occurs at the end of an iteration by encouraging (requiring?) a consistent pace throughout and tools like velocity and burndowns work well to plan and track progress.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked at several shops that practices various agile methodologies. The most interesting one had 4 "sessions" throughout the day that were about an hour and a half long, with a 20 minute break in between. Friday was Personal Dev day, so the last two sessions were for whatever you wanted to work on.

The key things for us were communication, really nailing down the concept of user stories, defining done to mean "in production", and trust. We also made sure to break the stories down into chunks that were no more than a day long, and ideally 1-2 development sessions. We typically swapped pairs every session to every other session.

Currently I run a 20+ person dev team which is partially distributed. The key tenant for me is sustainable pace - and that means I don't want my teams working > 40 hour weeks even occasionally. Obviously if someone wants to stay late and work on things, that's up to them, but in general I fight hard to make sure that we work within the velocity a 40-hour week gives us.